# Mongoose query to multiple values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have a Mongoose query question that I can't seem to figure out. I'm trying to query a schema to find all documents in the collection that  have a parameter specified user id in one of a few places... What I have so far is this:

Schema:

```
var Module = new Schema({
   template: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'template' },
   owner: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: false } },
   primary: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
   users: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
   data: [],
   children: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Module' }],
   parent: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Module' }
});
```

Query:

```
Module.find()
        .or([{owner: req.user.id}, {primary: req.user.id}])
        .populate('primary users children parent template')
        .exec(function (err, modules) {
    ...
    }
```

So as of now, it seems to correctly find documents that have the `req.user.id` as the primary or owner field, but how would I also return all documents where the users array is also searched for this value?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try just `.or([{owner: req.user.id}, {primary: req.user.id}, {users: req.user.id}])`, I believe Mongoose will do a sort of "indexOf" in the array with a query like that

Comment: Wow. That was really simple, didn't think it was something so easy. Thanks for that!